# Python Environments

Tags: python, pip, environment

Using a RaspberryPi 4b, I created a python environment called venv, activated the environment, ran pip install SpeechRecognition in the environment, and received the following error after running code to interpret a .wav file:

> OSError: FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent

So, I installed flac, using the `sudo apt-get install flac`, which corrected the error.

However, how do I install flac in my venv environment so it's packaged later with the app I'm creating?

Comment: There may be ways of packaging native library dependencies with your app, but that doesn't have anything to do with virtual environments.  Virtual environments just allow you to develop setups consisting of a particular version of Python and a set of Python modules.  When you install something with `apt-get`, you're basically enhancing the operating system of your host system.  The result of that install is available to all Python installations.  It doesn't matter what Python environment you were running when you did the install.

Comment: You don't need to, just install SpeechRecognition via pip. FLAC isn't installed to the virtual environment, it's installed to the host on which the virtual environment runs. Your app could be packaged with a script that installs the required system libraries, but this will be dependent upon the host operating system. The other option is to package your app with the libraries' source and build them within the project, but this is even more fragile than the previous option.

Comment: @CryptoFool Can I use something like Docker to package native library dependencies along with the required python packages? I want to avoid someone running the app with the python package using a requirements.txt and receiving the FLAC error because the native libraries are not correctly set.